# bash: illegal character in an environment variable

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, export

According to `man` `bash`, `bash` identifiers may consist: "only of alphanumeric characters and underscores", however, `bash` seems to have been tolerant to this up until `shellshock` patch. Actually, it still is, but now it just throws an annoying error message. I admit that I made a stupid decision when I decided to have dots in my function naming scheme, but I have more than 100 functions `named.like.this` and to make things worse, I depend on that structure, because they are organized in "classes", and call each other based on that naming scheme. I am looking for a solution to suppress this error message on a global scale, because it is highly impractical to change all the function names.

```
my.function(){ echo hello world;}
export -f my.function
tar --help
/bin/bash: error importing function definition for `BASH_FUNC_my.function'
Usage: tar -[cxtzjhmvO] [-X FILE] [-T FILE] [-f TARFILE] [-C DIR] [FILE]...
```

(it complains only for exported functions, but most of them need to be exported; bash version is 4.2.37)

Comment: I'd suggest you take the one-time pain to fix your design error. What you are asking for is to just mask the smell with an air freshener.

Comment: Or ignore stderr every time you export one of those functions, redirect to null... probably won't help with any actual errors though